# SQLAlchemy StaleDataError on deleting items inserted via ORM sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm having an issue where I get a an error such as this one:

```
"MyPyramidApplication Error"<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError'>: DELETE statement on table 'page_view' expected to delete 6 row(s); Only 0 were matched.
```

So, I have a good idea what is causing the issue but I have been unable to solve it.

I have a page_view model, that has a foreign key on `page_id` and a `user_id`.

Here's what the model looks like:

```
page_view_table = sa.Table(
   'page_view',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('page_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('guide.id')),
    sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    sa.Column('last_view', sa.DateTime, nullable=False),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'page_id'),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB',
    mysql_charset='utf8mb4'
)
```

Here's what the relations look like

```
orm.mapper(Page, page_table,
    properties = {
        'users_viewed': sa.orm.relation(
            User,
            secondary=page_view_table,
            backref='page'),
    }
)
```

I am adding some items to my database using an insert statement, something similar to this:

```
ins = model.page_view_table.insert()
sql = str(ins)
sql += ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_view = :last_view'
session = model.Session()
session.execute(sql, page_views)
mark_changed(session)
```

As far as I can tell from the logs, the transactions gets committed properly and I see the items in the DB.

However, when I try to delete the page item using the ORM, I get the StaleDataError exception.  Looking at the logs, I see the ORM issuing a delete statement but then rolling back due to the error.

I have tried experimenting with `session.expire_all()` as well as `session.expunge_all()` right after the insert statement but they weren't very helpful and I still the error.

Here's what I see in the SQLAlchemy logs.

```
2011-11-05 18:06:08,031 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][worker 3] DELETE FROM page_view WHERE page_view.page_id = %s AND page_view.user_id = %s
2011-11-05 18:06:08,031 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][worker 3] (13818L, 259L)
2011-11-05 18:06:08,032 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][worker 3] DELETE FROM page_view WHERE page_view.page_id = %s AND page_view.user_id = %s
2011-11-05 18:06:08,033 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][worker 3] (13818L, 259L)
2011-11-05 18:06:08,033 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][worker 3] ROLLBACK
```

I thought the double delete statement was  a suspect, maybe pointing to a misconfigured ORM relation but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 7):

I guess I can give a **hint** on this problem. The short version is: "You will probably have to modify data in the Database manually to solve the issue".

The longer version: I had a similar issue with SQLite. I had the following table mapped:

```
ingredients = Table('ingredients', metadata,
    Column('recipe_title', Unicode, ForeignKey('recipes.title'), primary_key=True),
    Column('product_title', Unicode, ForeignKey('products.title'), primary_key=True),
    Column('amount', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('unit_title', Unicode, ForeignKey('units.title')))
```

see that composite primary key? I somehow managed to insert two rows with the same recipe_title/product_title pair. I was surprized to find  out that there were not a single constraint on the side of SQLite for this table (no primary key, no fereign key - it was just a plain vanilla table), but well - thats the way sqlalchemy goes, not my business.

Then when I tried to delete a persited object involving those two rows, sqlalchemy saw that it's constraints were violated and it threw the 'StaleDataError'. Finally I just had to remove one duplicatinng row manually from SQLite table.

Answer (score 2):

Although columns can be marked as `primary_key`, make sure this is enforced on the database level as well (for example when the database was created by some different tool). In MySQL this means ensuring they are `PRIMARY KEY` and not only `KEY`.

In my case there were 2 columns marked as `primary_key` (composite) but  there were multiple rows containing the same (supposedly) unique `id`'s.

Comment: To improve this answer please reword --- such as "Although columns can be marked as primary_key the database may not enforce them as such. Ensure that they are PRIMARY KEY and not KEY by doing <insert required steps>" Or if this is not an answer to the original question please delete it.