# Deleting from many-to-many SQL-Alchemy and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete a child object from a many-to-many relationship in sql-alchemy.

I keep getting the following error:

```
StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'headings_locations' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched.
```

I have looked at a number of the existing stackexchange questions
    ([SQLAlchemy DELETE Error caused by having a both lazy-load AND a dynamic version of the same relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198595/sqlalchemy-delete-error-caused-by-having-a-both-lazy-load-and-a-dynamic-version), [SQLAlchemy StaleDataError on deleting items inserted via ORM sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024602/sqlalchemy-staledataerror-on-deleting-items-inserted-via-orm-sqlalchemy-orm-exc), [SQLAlchemy Attempting to Twice Delete Many to Many Secondary Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824401/sqlalchemy-attempting-to-twice-delete-many-to-many-secondary-relationship), [Delete from Many to Many Relationship in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497244/delete-from-many-to-many-relationship-in-mysql))
regarding this as well as read the documentation and can't figure out why it isn't working.

My code defining the relationships is as follows:

```
headings_locations = db.Table('headings_locations',
        db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
        db.Column('location_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('location.id')),
        db.Column('headings_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('headings.id')))


class Headings(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "headings"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    special = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    content = db.relationship('Content', backref=db.backref('heading'), cascade="all, delete-orphan") 
    created_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    modified_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name



class Location(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "location"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id')) 
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    created_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    modified_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    location_prefix = db.Column(db.Integer)
    numbers = db.relationship('Numbers', backref=db.backref('location'), cascade="all, delete-orphan") 
    headings = db.relationship('Headings', secondary=headings_locations, 
                            backref=db.backref('locations', lazy='dynamic', cascade="all"))


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

And my delete code is as follows:

```
@content_blueprint.route('/delete_content/<int:location_id>/<int:heading_id>')
@login_required
def delete_content(location_id, heading_id):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    location = db.session.query(Location).filter_by(id = location_id).first()
    heading = db.session.query(Headings).filter_by(id = heading_id).first()
    location.headings.remove(heading)
    #db.session.delete(heading)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Data Updated, thank-you')
    return redirect(url_for('content.add_heading', location_id=location_id))
```

Whichever way i try and remove the child object (db.session.delete(heading) or location.headings.remove(heading) I still get the same error.

Any help is much appreciated.

My database is postgresql.

Edit:
My code which adds the relationship:

```
        new_heading = Headings(form.new_heading.data)
        db.session.add(new_heading)
        location.headings.append(new_heading)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: One humble suggestion: the fastest way to debug a similar situation in any kind of ORM is to look at the table definitions generated by the system, then look at the SQL query generated. Usually it is immediately clear the reason of the error. If this is not the case, then ask that query directly to the DBMS (for instance with pgAdmin), and look at the error message produced.

Comment: @rob123 I think your relationship is not `many to many` between `Locations and Headings`, it seems like you have `one to many` between them, like `one Heading can have many Locations`, Ideally you can't delete `Headings` through `Locations` since you've a `ForeignKey` relation ship, this is because the `heading` you are trying to delete might have another `Location` and that is blocking your delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would assume that the error message is correct: indeed in your database you have 2 rows which link `Location` and `Heading` instances. In this case you should find out where and why did this happen in the first place, and prevent this from happening again

1. First, to confirm this assumption, you could run the following query against your database:

   ```
   q = session.query(
       headings_locations.c.location_id,
       headings_locations.c.heading_id,
       sa.func.count().label("# connections"),
   ).group_by(
       headings_locations.c.location_id,
       headings_locations.c.heading_id,
   ).having(
       sa.func.count() > 1
   )
   ```
2. Assuming, the assumption is confirmed, *fix* it by manually deleting all the duplicates in your database (leaving just one for each).
3. After that, add a [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint) to your `headings_locations` table:

   ```
   headings_locations = db.Table('headings_locations',
           db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
           db.Column('location_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('location.id')),
           db.Column('headings_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('headings.id')),
           db.UniqueConstraint('location_id', 'headings_id', name='UC_location_id_headings_id'),
   )
   ```

*Note that you need to need to add it to the database, it is not enough to add it to the `sqlalchemy` model.*

Now the code where the duplicates are inserted by mistake will fail with the unique constraint violation exception, and you can fix the root of the problem.

Comment: Well, you are exactly correct - the big question for me is why is it adding a second entry! I have updated my original post to reflect the code I use to save a new heading.
Thank-you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I do not know, but it could happen because of concurrency, for example. Having `UniqueContraint` helps to identify the problem as soon as it occurs.